# why the image keep a white space from the bottom and the top?

Tags: android, xml

what i have is an activity and i add an images to it, and i make it as background for the activity with the following xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash5" />     
</LinearLayout>
```

and the image size is : 550 px for width and 800 px for height

[image]

and as you can see from the image you can see a white space in top and in bottom .. why this is happening even it's fill parent for width and height?

Comment: android:ScaleType="fitXy" for imageview

Comment: or use android:background instead of android:src. It will stretch to fill. Other 2 notes: fill_parent is deprecated since API level 8 - use match_parent. and centerHorizontal or CenterVertical are only used in RelativaLayouts and ONLY if you use wrap_content, not_ match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash5"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"

      />     
</LinearLayout>
```